# inequalitysolution

Tags: differential-equations, functions, inequalities

I have a function for which I would like to solve an inequality and find a range of `r` with respect to other quantities. I am not well familiar with Mathematica, could you please help me to find it?

[image: the function]

[image: inequality equation]

```
f[r_] = 1 + (r^2)/(6 L) (1 - Sqrt[1 + 20 LM/r^5])

L (2 f'' + 4 f'/r) < 1
```

Comment: Take a look at `D` and `Reduce`.

Comment: I tried Reduce but it can not solve it

Comment: Show us the code that failed for you. Also notice that you need `f'[r]` not just `f'`.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem because `Reduce[L (2 f''[r] + 4 f'[r]/r) < 1, r]` works well, if you substitute for `M` and `L` and use `N` you get numerical values. All of that can be found searching for "inequalities" keyword etc. So unless there is a specific problem I will mark it as an easy to find/